# Does an unencrypted disk pose a risk to other encrypted disk's data?

Tags: disk-encryption, windows-10, veracrypt

I have three disks, only two are encrypted:

A: OS, encrypted
B: Main storage HDD, encrypted
C: Gaming only SSD, not encrypted.

Should I be worried that C: could cache/store sensitive data from A/B disks even if I only use it for storing games - assuming threat model of physical forensic analysis.

Comment: Keep in mind that disk encryption only protects your data if the physical drive is stolen.  Security protections are effective relative to the security risks they address.  In this case, drive encryption protects your data in the event of a drive theft, not from over-the-internet compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be safe if the configuration of the system is correct.

General cache, dump files, hibernation, etc should only be configured to be created on the OS drive.

In such a case there's no cache to be done in your gaming drive. Additionally, most games today drop their save-games in local user folders, not the game folder, so not even that would be a risk. Some log files may be created by games (crash logs, parsers, etc) on the games drive, but that does not contain information stored on the other 2 drives.

Comment: I would need to go out of my way for drive C: to contain "General cache, dump files, hibernation, etc" as that defaults to OS drive, correct?

Comment: Unless you specifically changed the locations to others than OS drive, they should all save there implicitly.